# Redirecting shell stdout from application run by mono

Tags: bash, shell, redirect, mono, stdout

I have run in to an interesting issue that I can't seem to work around so maybe you guru's can direct me in the right direction.
I want to have my app, which is run by mono direct its output to a logfile, but I want it to overwrite / empty the logfile before every write. Now it appends and I can't seem to change that no matter what.
Here are some of the options I've tried and their result:

```
mono myapp.exe > myapp.log &            Append
mono myapp.exe >| myapp.log &           Append
mono myapp.exe | tee myapp.log          Append
mono myapp.exe >! myapp.log &           Nothing
```

The above are called from within my bash-based startup script, which runs nicely otherwise. (just one iteration, don't need multiple) Directing to `/dev/null` is so far the best as it would otherwise grow the log file indefinitely.
Tha app outputs some info every 2 seconds and it'd be nice to view it with `tail -f myapp.log` whenever I wanted to.

Thank you for your time.

Comment: Your question is really poorly worded. Please edit it expressing yourself more clearly. Do you want the logfile to always contain the _last_ output line only?

Comment: No, as I said, I want every write to overwrite the previous contents. In this case it is a total of 21 lines.

Answer (score -1):

I don't get the problem, sorry. why not using **rm** and don't run the programms in background.

Or do you want just one specific line of the output ? In this case you need some additional tools like **head** or **sed** and you have to give more input.

Comment: It's a remote server, so background is pretty much a must.